# Self-Join SQL statement w/calculated data

Tags: mysql, self-join, calculated-columns

I have a table with the following data:

```
id  date    name    schedulenum paymentamt
1   12/2/2014   AB  077LR10 100
2   12/2/2014   AN  077LR10 200
3   12/2/2014   CD  077LR10 300
4   3/10/2015   AN  083LR12 200
5   3/10/2015   WC  083LR12 500
6   5/20/2015   AB  105LR20 200
7   5/20/2015   CD  105LR20 150
8   5/20/2015   RH  105LR20 150
9   5/20/2015   RG  105LR20 400
```

And I would like to write a query that would bring back the following results:

```
schedulenum paymentamt
077LR10 600
083LR12 700
105LR20 900
```

Basically I need to create a SQL statement that selects data from `Table A` that will result in 2 columns.  The first column would be a unique schedule number (i.e., `'schedulenum'` - there are multiple rows with the same `schedulenum`) and a total payment amount (`'paymentamt'`) per `schedulenum` (each row will have a different `'paymentamt'`). I think this would require a self-join but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Why isn't this just a sum of paymentamt grouping by schedulenum?  `SELECT schedulenum, sum(paymentamt) as TotalpaymentAmt from tableName group by scheduleNum`?  Seems to me you're trying to do aggregation.  I don't understand why you would need a self join.

Comment: Thank you! I was obviously over-thinking this!

Answer (score 0):

Use a group by when getting sums from one table.

```
select schedulenum, sum(payment) from mytable 
where schedulenum = x 
group by schhedulenum
```

...

```
select schedulenum, sum(payment) from mytable  
group by schhedulenum
order by schedulenum
```

Answer (score 0):

No self-join needed at all. What you want is the 'group by' keyword and aggregate functions.

```
SELECT schedulenum, sum(paymentamt) 
FROM [TABLE] 
GROUP BY schedulenum;
```